# Create MySQL Logfile that can be used as backup

Tags: mysql, cakephp-2.0

Every night the MySQL database is saved by a cronjob which uses mysqldump.

During the day, when the CakePHP application is running, I would like to have a logfile working, that could be used as backup in case of a damage happening during the day.

For recovery, it would be necessary to first run the recovery from the mysqldump that was established at night. And secondly, run the recovery from the logfile to get the database changes from the current day.

Does there exist such a logfile possibility and where or how could I get it?
Or are there any other ways to get a proper backup?

Comment: Google MySQL replication in order to avoid these "solutions" you had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

It's built into MySQL, you wouldn't do this in your applictation typically.

[enter link description here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlbinlog.html)

The binlogs do what you say - it is a binary file that contains every transaction that hits the database. So, if you had a nightly back up and the server crashed, you would recover the bin logs, export the transaction logs from the datetime of the last transaction in the database and essentially re-run or re-play every transaction from that point.

And having used it >10 times before ... it is awesome... but you have to turn in on in your my.conf file (google that) and manage the binlog files as they do get big on busy servers.